# Force app to fit on screen

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

I am trying to use an Android app which is not designed very well. Part of the UI is not visible which prevents it from functioning. Is there a way to force it to fit on screen? Possibly by overriding the display DPI with a developer option?

This is a screenshot of the app:

[image: Screenshot from Google Play Store. Yes, it says iPod. Lol.]
<sup>Screenshot from Google Play Store. Yes, it says iPod. Lol.</sup>

On my phone the "pairing" button is not visible as it is off the bottom of the display, and there is no scroll bar:

[image: Screenshot from my phone.]
<sup>Screenshot from my phone.</sup>

As you can see, the UI is simply too big to fit on the display, so some parts get pushed off. Since the UI does not scroll, they are inaccessible.

Comment: @beeshyams yes. it had no effect because that question is completely unrelated to mine. this app does not "place a menu on the system bar". in fact it does not have a menu of any kind. only buttons. which do not fit on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Retracted close vote and upvoted answer

Answer (score 2):

After googling for a while I found a solution. Enable `adb` debugging on the phone and run this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo
```

Find the part that says "density". This is the screen DPI. Reducing it will make Android think your screen is bigger, and it will shrink all of the UI respectively. I changed it from 240 to 200 by running this command:

```
adb shell wm density 200
```

Now the problem app looks like this, and I can use it:

[image: screenshot showing fixed app]
<sup>screenshot showing fixed app</sup>

Note that this will affect everything on the phone including the homescreen.

I found this solution [here](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/change-your-androids-screen-resolution-without-root-access-0160439/). Contrary to what that page says, I did not need to reboot for the change to take effect.